# How can I really maximize MS Paint in an external monitor in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, microsoft-paint, window-maximization

I use a GS76 Stealth 11UH laptop (4k monitor) running on Microsoft Windows 10 with a 1080p external monitor. When I try to maximize Microsoft Paint (`mspaint.exe`) in my external monitor in Windows 10, MS paint uses most of the screen but not all the screen: if I click on the edge of the screen (e.g., top or left), it will select the window behind Microsoft Paint.

[image]

How can I really maximize Microsoft Paint in my external monitor in Windows 10?

I do not have this issue if Microsoft Paint is in the built-in monitor in my laptop, or with the few other programs I tested.

---

Settings of each monitor if that matters:

[image]

Monitor 1 (4k):

[image]

[image]

Monitor 2 (1080p):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no way to really maximize MS Paint in an external monitor in Windows 10. It's just one of the many bugs/limitations that come with Windows 10.